# The speed of scraping tweet on a remote server depends on what?

Tags: javascript, python, twitter, web-applications

I am working on my first webapp project which I plan to publish using a remote server. I have a question about the architecture.

My webapp is to scrape tweets using [`twitterscraper`](https://github.com/taspinar/twitterscraper) Python package. A user who visits the website enters some keywords and click "Scrape" button. A Python backend scrapes the tweets containing the keywords, goes through some Natural Language Processing analysis, and visualise the result in charts. This `twitterscraper` package lets you scrape tweets using `Beautiful Soup`, therefore you don't need to create an API credential. The scraping speed depends on the bandwidth of the internet that you are using.

I made a Python script, JavaScript file, html file and css file. In my local environment the webapp works perfectly.

So the question is, after I put these files on the hosting server and publish the webapp, when a user clicks "Scrape" button, on what does the scraping speed depend? The bandwidth of the internet that the user is using? Or is there any "bandwidth" that the server is relying on?

As I said I am very new to this kind of architecture. So it would also be nice to suggest me an alternative way for structuring this kind of webapp. Thank you!

Comment: what data do you exchange with the remote server?

I suppose you send some kind of HTTP request and the server responds with some data, but how large is the response?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what exactly you asked, but could you tell me the definition of the "size of response"? If it's about the size of the tweet data, the webapp will scrape 2000-5000 tweets once you click "Scrape" button. But what the user will be shown is a chart, which is a result of the analysis of collected tweets.

Comment: What I meant by 'size' is the length of the data in kilobytes or whatever unit fits best. Also I am more interested in the data that will be transfered from the server to the client.

Comment: Ok, so the size of the scraped tweets are 0.2-0.3MB. It will go though some data transformation, preparation and enrichment and the final data on which the visualisation is made is about 0.8MB, which will be the size of the data transferred from the server to the client.

Comment: In that case, network shouldn't be that much of an issue, your bottleneck, if any, will probably be server-side

Comment: alright, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where the bottle-neck is depends on a bunch of different variables.

If you're doing a lot of data manipulation, but you don't have a lot of CPU time allocated to the program (i.e. there are too many users for your processor to handle), it could slow down there.

If you don't have sufficient memory, and you're trying to parse and return a lot of data, it could slow down there.

Because you're also talking to Twitter, whatever the bandwidth restrictions are between your server and the twitter server will affect the speed at which you can retrieve results from their API, and so the time it takes your program to respond to a user.

There's also the connection between yourself and the user. If that's slow, it could affect your program.